# Using application insights, metrics tracking is ok, but can not find the logs

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, azure-application-insights

I set up a POC/demo project to test application insights in order to have a full observability experience.
I think I followed the different recommandation, like using the [workspace-based application insight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/create-workspace-resource) resource, using [the connection string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/migrate-from-instrumentation-keys-to-connection-strings) approach (rather than the instrumentation key one), and used the C#/.net 6 minimal web api project template modified as [described to enable/configure the application insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core) telemetry.

When I run my example, everything works fine regarding metrics, live metrics, application maps up to the application insight workspace (I can visualize charts, see the live metrics, start a map...).

BUT I can not see any logs... Where should I find those? How can I trouble shoot this?

(I added a console output for the loggs just to check if filtering is ok, but it works also...)

Comment: You should be able to see it in the log analytics configured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do mind that if you write logs using the `ILogger` interface with severity level "Information" like this `_logger.LogInformation("Some Info");` you need to adjust the loglevel settings because the default settings only log trace telemetry of level warning and up.

You can modify that in the configuration (also, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core?tabs=netcorenew%2Cnetcore6#how-do-i-customize-ilogger-logs-collection)):

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can use the transaction search in the portal:

[image]

Or you can query the workspace directly:

[image]

Comment: I was missing the dedicated log level configuration (even if the documentation was emphasizing that)
Sorry, & thank you!